# When should the program greet with good evening and good night?

Tags: time, programming, greetings

I want to create a program that will greet users with good morning, good afternoon, good evening and good night. However, I am confused as to when the time should be used to greet with good evening and good night on the program.

So, when is the best time to say good evening and good night on the program? And also is it necessary to say good night to the users of the program?

Comment: In my part of the world "good night" isn't used as a greeting.

Comment: Collins Cobuild dictionary says how to use the phrases (as will most English learners dictionaries). https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/goodnight

Comment: https://codescracker.com/c/program/c-program-print-message-according-time.htm
How about this?